# Как для двух секций установить один общий фон?

Tags: html, css

**Например для этого кода**

```html
<nav class="section-first">
//Cодержимое
</nav>
<!--/.section-first-->

<main class="section-second">
//Cодержимое
</main>
 <!--/.section-second-->
```

Разные способы пробовала не получается.

Типа вот такое(это конечно скрин не оригинального макета)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Одинаковый фон или единый для двух секций?

Comment: Единый. Одинаковый это проще простого

Comment: @devafina Если для приведенной структуры html - никак. Можно обернуть всё в `<div class="container">...</div>` и для него уже прописать фон (класс может называться как угодно, это для примера).

Comment: Вот именно для этой структуры мне надо(Я и так знала что ответ для этого никак, но на всякий случай задала вопрос) пробовала, Я такое <div class="container">...</div> пробовала, не по макету получилось.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Не для обычных блоков(<div>...</div>) а именно для блоков созданных с помощью семантических элементов.

Comment: Приведите скрин того что должно получиться !

Comment: @HamSter вставила скрин выше

Comment: @Sevastopol' Да

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если знаете высоту блока навигации:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  --nav-vertical-size: 100px;
}

main,
nav {
  background-image: url(https://euro-travels.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Alpy.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

nav {
  height: var(--nav-vertical-size);
  background-position: center 0;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - var(--nav-vertical-size));
  background-position: center calc(-1 * var(--nav-vertical-size));
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<main></main>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогло мне. Кому-то наверное поможет

Comment: @devafina и почему не помогло? Вы не знаете высоту `<nav>`?

Comment: Наконец-то получилось ) Высота известна. Просто я забыла удалить из  блока nav ранее добавленное свойство height(высота же у меня в body устанавливается через переменной --nav-vertical-size), из-за не сработало правильно. Ваш ответ помог мне. Спасибо еще раз ) И еще свойство filter вообще не надо написать(вы наверное для различия nav и main добавили это свойство)